SMA of 50 days volume if close > close[1] using STOCKHISTORY function
I need Simple Moving Average of 50 days volume if current close price is greater than close of previous day using STOCKHISTORY function in excel.
I tried comparing close price using SCAN function but not sure how to get volume value of matching condition.
=SCAN(0,STOCKHISTORY(A2, TODAY()-50, TODAY(),0,0,1), LAMBDA(x,y,IF(x>y, x+y, y)))


Again, still not sure what you mean by 50 days, but I rewrote the formula to return the AVERAGE of the volume on the last 50 Trading days where the price exceeded the previous trading days price.
=LET(
    sh, STOCKHISTORY(A2, TODAY() - 200, TODAY(), 0, 0, 0, 1, 5),
    GT, DROP(
        VSTACK({TRUE}, DROP(CHOOSECOLS(sh, 2), 1) > CHOOSECOLS(sh, 2)),
        -1
    ),
    volFilter, FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(sh, 3), GT),
    last50, CHOOSEROWS(
        volFilter,
        SEQUENCE(50, , ROWS(volFilter) - 49, 1)
    ),
    AVERAGE(last50)
)


sh: Download enough days so we will have 50 left after filtering Might need to do a test to ensure we have 50 days
GT: Create a {TRUE;FALSE} array to use in the FILTER function to return only those volumes where Close > prev day Close
volFilter: Apply the Filter and return only the volume column
last50: Return the last 50 volume entries


I want to compare every close price to its previous day close price. If it is higher, I want to sum volume of that day and calculate average

@LalitChattar And do you mean 50 calendar days? trading days? or 50 days when the close price meets your criteria?
